# AngularJS directive loaded dynamically in ng-include do not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have a custom directive which adds some html.

```
myAppModule.directive('myDirective', function() {
    var linker = function(scope, element) {
        return element.html("<b>directive loaded</b>");
    };
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        rep1ace: true,
        link: linker,
        scope: false
    };
});
```

This directive is loaded and used in a dynamically loaded html which is included via `ng-include`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dynamicscript.js"></script>
<my-directive>...</my-directive>
```

But it does't work. The `linker`-function is never called. 
It works if I move the `dynamicscript.js` script loading from the included html to the `index.html`.

[Here is the Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ibf1gxFfL10xRXGTzgnt?p=preview)

Comment: I dont think you can include JS scripts from within Angular templates.

Comment: The script is called and the directive is added to the app module. But it is not applied to `<my-directive>`

Comment: That's because `ngInclude` runs after Angular has compiled the page. Bootstraping manually might help.

Comment: Not sure about bootstraping too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load the controllers, directives, and so on.

Using special plugins, CSS and HTML files can be loaded too.

Here is a great example from Ben Nadel: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2554-Loading-AngularJS-Components-With-RequireJS-After-Application-Bootstrap.htm

Answer (score 0):

All JS files should be included in 'index.html'
JS files (services, modules, controllers) loaded dynamically using ng-include will not work

Comment: in angular 1.1.5, loading the controller in included html fiels worked well. In 1.2 not even this is working correct anymore. But Why? Is there a workaround?