# Is ngInclude only for partial template purposes, or can I share other Angular Apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

So I apologize in advance if this has been answered, tried my best to look through similar stacks, but basically I'm curious about the scope of ngInclude functionality.

Does it have a single purpose as the question poses, as a partial template render feature?

Or could I set up a partial with an angular script embedded that would run on implementation on a different URI/route, given that page serves up Angular as well.

I'm looking for an optimal way of sharing angular interface across services other than using an iframe for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best understanding of the angular `ng-include` is that it doesn't run scripts by default which means you really can't include new directive definitions or other angular/javascript components in a partial. To support that I did a bit of research and found the following links:

- **Dynamic Directive** - [AngularJS directive loaded dynamically in ng-include do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121985/angularjs-directive-loaded-dynamically-in-ng-include-do-not-work)
- **Load Script From Partial** - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/H4haaMePJU0

Personally I ran into something somewhat similar on [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454416/including-tripadvisor-widget-in-angularjs-app) where javascript is included dynamically but doesn't get run. You can manually run javascript using a custom directive but it isn't extremely easy.

**Bottom Line** - I think the bottom line here is if you *need* to include scripts in a partial there are ways to do it but it is extra work and isn't supported terribly well.